# Moving historical SVN commits into existing Github repo?

Tags: git, svn, github

Some time ago I moved a Subversion repository over to Git and github when I decided to Open Source some software, and I'm not sure what I did but the commit history wasn't moved over. At the time I thought I didn't care, but now I think I would actually quite like the 2+ years of commits in Github, if for no other reason than a record of work effort.  The problem is that my project has been on Github for a while and has been forked and received commits since it was created.

Is there a way to "back port" the historical commits from my old repo, and put them into the living, breathing Github repo?

Note: I half-heartedly tried `svn2git --rebase` but I'm not sure if this will work considering there have been commits since the svn repo was left behind.  I got this error and I'm not sure what it means:

```
 command failed:
 2>&1 git svn fetch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ancestry in git is nothing more than a commit (which is a text file) containing one or more lines that read `parent <hash of parent commit>`. If you want to insert history before your first commit, it would need a parent line like this (first commits do not have one), and that would change the first commit's hash, which would mean its descendant(s) would need to change parent pointers, and this goes recursively up through all commits, as all are descended from the repo's first commit.

If you're not worried about messing up people working on forks (because you will be changing history in your project), then you can just redo the operation to create a second git repo of the old history, add that repo as a remote to your new repo, and fetch in the changes, Now you'll have two roots in your new repo. You may get a warning about no commits in common; this is fine. Now you can view history to get your bearings: `git log --all --graph --oneline --decorate`, then probably do a `rebase --onto` to move the new repo's new work on top of the old repo's history you just brought in. Presumably the tree in your new repo's first commit will be identical to the tree in your old repo's last, so this may be as simple as: `git rebase --onto A B C`, where `A` is the last commit in the old repo's history, which you just brought in, `B` is the first commit in the new repo (which is here being considered the "old base" of the new repo, which you aren't rebasing onto the old history, because it should be identical, and `C`, which is the head of the branch in the new repo that you want to rebase onto this, likely `master`.

Your repos may be more complicated than that, and you may need to do more work to figure out exactly where the seam is for rejoining things, but that's the general idea. Now you can `git remote rm newrepo`, "newrepo" being whatever you named the remote when adding it. That should clear out the second root and all the fetched-in commits. Finally, you can force push this to github. This will have changed literally every commit hash, so none of the forks will work, but you'll have all the history, and people could just clone again, or `reset --hard` to the new `master` to catch back up. You'll probably want to inform everyone of this on your repo page, and maybe find the people who forked and alert them of your intentions.